# Swift - SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete - how to deal with it?

Tags: ios, swift, autocomplete, uisearchbar, google-places-api

My research showed that the only proper way to have an autocompletion search bar which retrieves coordinates is to use SPGooglePlacesAutoComplete.

However, here https://github.com/spoletto/SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete are only installation hints along with bridging from obj-c to swift. But actually, I cannot find anywhere how to handle it in swift. How to connect search bar outlet, how to connect it to existing project with map etc.

Does anybody know some neat tutorial which makes handling this library in swift clear? If no such thing around the web, could anybody post here, as an answer, short tutorial how to deal with SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete, how to connect outlets, retrieve coordinates, how to pair it with search bar etc. I would be very grateful

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

as the person who maintains https://github.com/chenyuan/SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete (in a very inactive way), I have received several inquires about supporting Swift. I'm planning to migrate this repo to Swift, however with a full-time job and 2 kids, I can't promise a specific timeline.

Meanwhile, would you be able to follow the solutions provided in this issue: https://github.com/chenyuan/SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete/issues/15

Comment: please try this new repo: https://github.com/hkellaway/HNKGooglePlacesAutocomplete, which is being actively maintained.